# How to dump all the predefined symbols?

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

I am wondering how I could dump the predefined symbols used by the codeblocks compiler. The reason I need to do this is because I am trying to compile an external library and it is giving me errors such as :

..\ac-config.linux32.h|216|error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long int int32_t'|
 c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1........\include\stdint.h|31|error:   'int32_t' has a previous declaration as 'typedef int int32_t'|
..\ac-config.linux32.h|218|error: conflicting declaration 'typedef char int8_t'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1........\include\stdint.h|27|error: 'int8_t' has a previous declaration as 'typedef signed char int8_t'|
..\ac-config.linux32.h|221|error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long unsigned int uint32_t'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1........\include\stdint.h|32|error: 'uint32_t' has a previous declaration as 'typedef unsigned int uint32_t'|
||=== Build finished: 6 errors, 0 warnings ===|

I am somewhat of a beginner(student) so if possible, I need the explanations to be as simple as possible.

Thank You very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cpp -dM /dev/null | wc -l 
224
$ cpp -dM /dev/null | head
#define __DBL_MIN_EXP__ (-1021)
#define __pentiumpro__ 1
#define __UINT_LEAST16_MAX__ 65535
#define __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE 2
#define __FLT_MIN__ 1.17549435082228750797e-38F
#define __UINT_LEAST8_TYPE__ unsigned char
#define __INTMAX_C(c) c ## LL
#define __CHAR_BIT__ 8
#define __UINT8_MAX__ 255
#define __WINT_MAX__ 4294967295U
```